# Issue with indentation in HAML-"rest of document was indented using 2 spaces"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, indentation

I would have posted this in a Github Gist or using Tinkerbin, but the indentation appears WAY off when I copy and paste my HAML.

The error message is: Inconsistent indentation: "\t\t  " was used for indentation, but the rest of the document was indented using 2 spaces.

I posted an imgur to show you where the error is happening, the browser is telling me line 8, as you can see in the photo.

Bear with me, this is probably an easy fix but I am very new to HAML.

[image: haml indentaion issue]

Comment: If the indentation appears "way off" then you're not indenting correctly--are you using spaces instead of tabs? You should be consistent--the error message indicates you're not. (I don't know what HAML requires; I always use spaces, like a sane person. *Let the battle begin.*)

Comment: Indentation appearing way off when copied and pasted somewhere else is a surefire sign you did something wrong ;) Never mix tabs and spaces for indentation.

Comment: Well I have my tab size set to 2 at the bottom of Textmate. So wait, even if one tab or 2 spaces yields the same 'amount' of space, using both interchangeably can mess things up? And yes fwiw I've been using both :x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use either space or tab,
or you can select all and convert into spaces once finish your code, [SUBLIME](http://www.sublimetext.com/) text editor is best for it

Comment: Yes you're completely right, I was getting errors mixing both. Silly HAML! :) Great learning experience though.

Comment: I wouldn't risk a statement that sublime text editor is best, what's wrong with vim? :)

Answer (score 9):

If you're using SublimeText, add the following to Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings

```
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
```

... then re-paste the code and all tabs will be changed to spaces.

Comment: If you're using sublime, then this is the way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ruby on Rails, make sure to make the indentation consistent with application.html.haml in views/layouts